# Apply transparency on pixels in an image with PyQGIS

Tags: raster, gdal, pyqgis, ogr

I'm trying to grab the pixels that intersect with my polygon shapefile and apply transparency to them (that is, I'm trying to create a hole in my raster)

For that, I get all the pixels that are in the footprint of the shapefile in a list (see code below)

Then I used the `QgsRasterTransparency.TransparentThreeValuePixel ()` class to apply transparency, but I get an error message:

> Error message: AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute
>   'renderer'

Code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
import numpy as np


iface = qgis.utils.iface

layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
raster = gdal.Open("F:\\MASTER GEOM\\MasterGeomatique_data\\PLEIADES\\PLEIADES_20130415_COLNAT.TIF")
print(raster)

transform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
xOrigin = transform[0]
yOrigin = transform[3]
pixelWidth = transform[1]
pixelHeight = transform[5]
print xOrigin, yOrigin


shp = ogr.Open("F:\essai.shp")
lyr = shp.GetLayer()
feat = lyr.GetNextFeature()
geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()

if (geom.GetGeometryName() == 'POLYGON'):
    ring = geom.GetGeometryRef(0)
    numpoints = ring.GetPointCount()
    pointsX = []; pointsY = []
    for p in range(numpoints):
                lon, lat, z = ring.GetPoint(p)
                pointsX.append(lon)
                pointsY.append(lat)
                #print (pointsX)
xmin = min(pointsX)
xmax = max(pointsX)
ymin = min(pointsY)
ymax = max(pointsY)
print xmin, ymin
print xmax, ymax  
 # Specify offset and rows and columns to read
xoff = int((xmin - xOrigin)/pixelWidth)
yoff = int((yOrigin - ymax)/pixelWidth)
xcount = int((xmax - xmin)/pixelWidth)+1
ycount = int((ymax - ymin)/pixelWidth)+1
print xoff, yoff
print xcount, ycount

bandList = []
# retrieve pixel on region of interest
for i in range(raster.RasterCount):
    band = raster.GetRasterBand(i+1)
    data = band.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount)
    bandList.append(data)

# Apply transparency using QgsRasterTransparency.TransparentThreeValuePixel()
active_layer = raster
raster_transparency  = active_layer.renderer().rasterTransparency()
ltr = QgsRasterTransparency.TransparentThreeValuePixel()
tr_list = []
ltr.min = np.min(bandList)
ltr.max = np.max(bandList)
ltr.percentTransparent = 100  
tr_list.append(ltr)  
active_layer.renderer().rasterTransparency().setTransparentThreeValuePixelList(tr_list)
active_layer.triggerRepaint() 

# Refresh canvas
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(raster)

# Message d'erreur : AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'renderer'
```

Comment: Welcome back to GIS SE. Please take the [Tour]. Please immediately edit your question to 1) Use mixed case in the title (ALL CAPS is difficult to read and attracts downvotes) and 2) Indent your code so it is legible (highlight and press the `{}` button)

Comment: As in the first answer, you are are mixing gdal data and pyqgis data. Can you update the code to a correct use of only gdal or only pyqgis or if you want to mox do the appropriate conversions? Using pyqgis can be studied in pyqgis cookbook

Answer (score 2):

I don't think using `gdal.open` returns a [QgsRasterLayer](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterLayer.html#a5b8b070b403206d7552aa133a1d0336c) object, which you need to access it's renderer.

Try replacing:

```
raster = gdal.Open("F:\\MASTER GEOM\\MasterGeomatique_data\\PLEIADES\\PLEIADES_20130415_COLNAT.TIF")
```

with:

```
raster = QgsRasterLayer("F:\\MASTER GEOM\\MasterGeomatique_data\\PLEIADES\\PLEIADES_20130415_COLNAT.TIF", gdal)
```

Comment: I tried this before but it returns another error message like transform = rlayer.GetGeoTransform ()
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'GetGeoTransform'